# VBA Function gets "Argument Not Optional" error

Tags: vba, excel, function, selenium-webdriver, arguments

I am trying to fix a VBA that uses Selenium1.0.23 to open a site and login. My client said everything is working on his end except that the VBA must be putting the wrong Username and Password because the site is giving the wrong username-password message.
Now I got the script and try to run it but I got stuck on the functions giving "Argument Not Optional". Below is the script:

Here is the part with error. It highlights the ".setVariation" part.

```
Private Function setVariationOnPage(browser As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver, variations As Scripting.Dictionary) As Long
Dim name
For Each name In variations.keys
    ProductVariations.setVariation browser, variations(name)
Next name 
End Function
```

I believe the above function is calling another function on a separate module because there is a module name ProductVariations and a function called setvariation in it.

```
Public Function setVariation(browser As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver, ByVal name As String, value As String)
On Error GoTo setVariationError

Dim li As WebElement
Dim lis As Collection

Set lis = getVariationListItems(browser, name)
If lis Is Nothing Then
    GoTo setVariationError
    Exit Function
End If


For Each li In lis

    Dim link As WebElement
    Set link = getLinkFromVariationListItem(li)

    If LCase(Trim(getVariationValueNameFromListItem(li))) = LCase(Trim(value)) Then
        If InStr(li.getAttribute("class"), "active") = 0 Then
            link.Click
            ScrapingUtil.waitForPageToLoad browser
            If InStr(li.getAttribute("class"), "active") = 0 Then
                GoTo setVariationError
            End If
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
Next li

setVariationError:
Dim msg As String
msg = "Unable to set variation: ""{name}"" = ""{value}"""
msg = Replace(msg, "{name}", name)
msg = Replace(msg, "{value}", value)
Err.Description = msg
Err.raise 1
End Function
```

Then obviously this function calls another function and that function calls another. It's hell to troubleshoot it and I really need help.

Comment: setvariation function need 3 parameters to be Passed. as per above it passing two`browser, variations(name)`.

Comment: Based on the fact that the keys are called "name", maybe the call should be `ProductVariations.setVariation browser, name, variations(name)`?

Comment: if 3 rd parameter not need make it as optional `Public Function setVariation(browser As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver, ByVal name As String, optional value As String)`.

Comment: @fakedad tnx for trying to help.

Comment: @HA560 man your awesome. i made the 3rd param optional. amazing job! the guy who made this macro made my life hell. I still have more functions to figure out. the guy made multiple modules and functions for scraping data. anyways, thanks again man. i just wish i can put each and every error i get from this macro here. hahaha

Comment: @HA560 how do i mark this solved by you. newbie here. :)

Comment: Posted in ans section..click as an answer

Comment: making 3rd parameter as `Optional` doesn't seem the right solution. It certainly avoids compile time errors but it most probably leads to runtime problems (see my comments at @HA560 answer). I think you must try and understand the `value` argument role and pass it _consciously_. I'd first go with fakedad proposal

Answer (score -1):

making parameter as optional..

```
 Public Function setVariation(browser As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver, ByVal name As String, optional value As String).
```

Comment: but `value` argument is used in `If LCase(Trim(getVariationValueNameFromListItem(li))) = LCase(Trim(value)) Then`. Making it `Optional` will have it set to an empty string `""` anytime that function is called without passing the third parameter (like `ProductVariations.setVariation browser, variations(name)`) and thus that check would always presumably result `False` this way never triggering code inside its `If-Then-Else` block

Comment: This site is, and will be, attended by many people other than the questioner. So while this latter is likely to rate the answer mainly by its usefulness, other users will rate it by its precision and completeness, in favor of all users who'll bump into this post.